# How can I view the Git history for a folder, in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code provides multiple ways to view git history for a file, but there seems to be no way to see the git history for a folder.

VS Code has the new "Timeline view", introduced in March 2020, but it only supports git history for a file, not a folder.

- [Timeline support for folders · Issue #95332 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95332)
- [Visual Studio Code March 2020 - Timeline view](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_timeline-view)
- [Version Control in Visual Studio Code - Timeline view](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_timeline-view)

Comment: git doesn’t track folders. There’s likely a way to see the history of files in a given location

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the recent GitLens version (11.4.0, released on 2021-04-08) : https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

This VSCode extension has just introduced a way to display the git history of a folder. Right click on a folder in the file explorer tree, select `Open Folder History` and you should then see the expected log in a dedicated view.

[image]